# How to delete the lowest number in an array, and if there's several minimum numbers, delete the first

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, minimum

I'm trying to make a script, where the input is an array with random numbers. I try to delete the lowest number in the array which is no problem. But if there are several occurrences of this number in the array, how do I make sure that it is only the first occurrence of this number that gets deleted?

Let's say we have the following array:

```
a = np.array([2,6,2,1,6,1,9])
```

Here the lowest number is 1, but since it occurs two times, I only want to remove the first occurence so i get the following array as a result:

```
 a = np.array([2,6,2,6,1,9])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using NumPy, not native Python lists:

```
a = np.array([2,6,2,1,6,1,9])

a = np.delete(a, a.argmin())

print(a)
# [2 6 2 6 1 9]
```

[`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html): Return a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.

[`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html): Returns the indices of the minimum values along an axis.

With a NumPy array, you cannot delete elemensts with `del` as you can in a list.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this with a native Python `list` is:

```
>> a = [1,2,3,4,1,2,1]
>> del a[a.index(min(a))]
>> a
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simple do two things first sort and then shift array. For example

```
var list = [2, 1, 4, 5, 1];
list=list.sort(); // result would be like this [1,1,2,4,5]
list=list.shift();// result would be [1,2,4,5]
```

Comment: @Brad Solomon can you tell me what is wrong with above script.

Comment: It's written in JavaScript, for starters.

Comment: Ok i just give him idea to do like this becoz i dont know python